# Speedstep and Intel x5570?

Tags: central-processing-unit, intel, xeon

My new server has 2 x X5570 CPUs.

Now here is the output of grep -i hz /proc/cpuinfo

```
model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5570  @ 2.93GHz
cpu MHz  : 1600.231
model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5570  @ 2.93GHz
cpu MHz  : 1600.231
model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5570  @ 2.93GHz
cpu MHz  : 1600.231
model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5570  @ 2.93GHz
cpu MHz  : 1600.231
model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5570  @ 2.93GHz
cpu MHz  : 1600.231
model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5570  @ 2.93GHz
cpu MHz  : 1600.231
model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5570  @ 2.93GHz
cpu MHz  : 1600.231
model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5570  @ 2.93GHz
cpu MHz  : 1600.231
model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5570  @ 2.93GHz
cpu MHz  : 1600.231
model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5570  @ 2.93GHz
cpu MHz  : 1600.231
model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5570  @ 2.93GHz
cpu MHz  : 1600.231
model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5570  @ 2.93GHz
cpu MHz  : 1600.231
model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5570  @ 2.93GHz
cpu MHz  : 1600.231
model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5570  @ 2.93GHz
cpu MHz  : 1600.231
model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5570  @ 2.93GHz
cpu MHz  : 1600.231
model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5570  @ 2.93GHz
cpu MHz  : 1600.231
```

It always remains the same.. no matter how much load is mysql or any other app hogging. Even when mysql eats 2 or 3 CPUs at 100% each, the output of cpuinfo is the same.

If fact mysql performance for some heavy inserts is poorer than my old E5430 server.

Any clues? I contacted the server provider, they tried turning off SpeedStep and still we see the same results.

Any insights would be helpful cause I am paying heavily for this box and would love to milk all juice i can.

Comment: What's the server model and OS? You should certainly be seeing at least the 2.93Mhz base speed and under load with up to 4 cores the busy cores should ramp up to 3.2Ghz via Turboboost.

Comment: uname -a : Linux xxxxx.xxxxxx.com 2.6.30.8-64.fc11.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Sep 25 04:43:32 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Brand im unsure, how to check? Its a dedicated server with SoftLayer

Comment: This RedHat article has some good pointers, they may not apply directly to your distro but it should get you started in your discussions with Softlayer.  http://kbase.redhat.com/faq/docs/DOC-17124

Answer (score 1):

/proc/cpuinfo isnt your currently cpu usage speed, its you hardware info on cpu.

you have to at least use top to see your current usages.

Answer (score 1):

The powertop utility can display this type of information.

Answer (score 0):

You want to install lm_sensors, cpufrequtils and cpufreqd.  Cpufreqd is a daemon that can manage assigning different 'governors', like 'ondemand' or 'conservative.'  Cpufrequtils set and get the status of the CPU's.  Lm_sensors monitors the cores so you know what's really the impact of the changes.  You also might need an appropriate kernel module loaded, like acpi_cpufreq.ko but that's starting to get into a chip/chipset specific settings.